# No result while filtering pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter, python-datetime

I'm trying to filter dataframe using a column but the filter does not seem to give any result or error. Following is the code :-

```
df = pd.read_csv('/kaggle/input/6-year-nifty50-historical-data-of-5-30-min-candle/30min_N50_10yr.csv')
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.date
df['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.time
df.drop(columns={'volume' , 'date'} , inplace = True)
df = df[['Date', 'Timestamp' , 'open' , 'high' , 'low' , 'close']]
df.set_index('Date' , inplace = True)
df.head(5)

>   Timestamp   open    high    low close Date                  
> 2015-01-09    09:15:00    8285.45 8303.00 8277.40 8285.55
> 2015-01-09    09:45:00    8285.40 8287.65 8273.95 8281.55
> 2015-01-09    10:15:00    8281.50 8291.45 8277.95 8281.35
> 2015-01-09    10:45:00    8281.30 8288.85 8279.10 8282.35
> 2015-01-09    11:15:00    8282.55 8283.20 8250.20 8255.65

filt = df['Timestamp'] == "09:15:00"
initial_balance = df.loc[filt]
initial_balance 
initial_balance
```

the above filter when applied produces no result and no error. I am expecting a new dataframe initial_balance which only contains rows of timestamp 09:15:00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use a string to compare to a time.

Rather use:

```
filt = df['Timestamp'] == pd.Timestamp("09:15:00").time()
initial_balance = df.loc[filt]
```

Or:

```
from datetime import time
filt = df['Timestamp'] == time(9, 15)
initial_balance = df.loc[filt]
```

Output:

```
           Timestamp      open      high       low     close
Date                                                        
2015-01-09  09:15:00   8285.45   8303.00   8277.40   8285.55
2015-01-12  09:15:00   8291.35   8291.35   8245.60   8271.10
2015-01-13  09:15:00   8346.15   8355.90   8322.00   8340.45
2015-01-14  09:15:00   8307.25   8323.30   8286.85   8318.50
2015-01-15  09:15:00   8425.20   8452.65   8380.75   8412.85
...              ...       ...       ...       ...       ...
2021-03-19  09:15:00  14471.15  14490.80  14350.50  14420.70
2021-03-22  09:15:00  14736.30  14736.30  14651.15  14717.75
2021-03-23  09:15:00  14768.55  14843.25  14747.75  14799.30
2021-03-24  09:15:00  14712.45  14752.15  14709.50  14736.05
2021-03-25  09:15:00  14570.90  14570.90  14432.70  14445.95

[1531 rows x 5 columns]
```